# quoteReplacement method in Matcher class

Tags: java, regex

The doc says 
"*method produces a String that will work as a literal replacement s in the appendReplacement method of the Matcher class. The String produced will match the sequence of characters in s treated as a literal sequence. Slashes ('\') and dollar signs ('$') will be given no special meaning*"

so its to imply that if I pass `Matcher.quoteReplacement("\n")`, I should get the output as literal `\n` string rather than a `newLine` character.
But I still get the newLine char from this method. 
Ironically, it works if I pass the `$` to the quoteReplacement method

quoteReplacement method works if you pass double-slash n

Comment: Sorry for my confusing answer. I wrongly thought \n was interpreted as a newline in a replacement, but it doesn't. Apparently, the backslash is only used to escape $ and \ in a replacement. So, if the user enters a literal replacement that potentially contains a $ or a \, quoteReplacelement makes sure these two characters are interpreted literally.

Comment: Excuse me, what is the question?